# Bootstrap 3 - Sizing & alignment issues

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, kendo-ui

I am integrating Bootstrap 3 with Kendo UI controls.

I am having alignment issues with multiple form-horizontal sections, here is the HTML

```
            <ul id="acc-form-panelbar">
            <li class="k-state-active">
                <span class="k-link k-state-selected">Project Info</span>
                <section style="padding:10px 0;">
                    <div class="form-horizontal form-widgets col-sm-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="procod">Project Code</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                <input id="procod" style="width: 25%;"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-horizontal form-widgets col-sm-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="proshocod">Project Short Code</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                <input id="proshocod" style="width: 25%;"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    <div class="form-horizontal form-widgets col-sm-12">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="protit">Project Title</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <input id="protit" style="width: 75%;" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
                </li>
            <li class="">
                <span class="k-link">Users Info</span>
                <div class="row" style="margin: 20px 0;">
                    <div class="form-horizontal form-widgets col-sm-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="name">Name</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                <input id="name" value="Bilal Haidar" style="width: 75%;" /> <!-- styles="width:100%;" -->
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="birthday">Birthday</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                <input id="birthday" type="date" value="10/09/1979" style="width: 75%;" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="gender">Gender</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                <select id="gender" style="width: 75%;"><option value="Male" selected="selected">Male</option><option value="Female">Female</option></select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="language">Language</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                <select id="language" style="width: 75%;"><option value="English" selected="selected">English</option><option value="German">German</option></select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

Anyone can tell me what's wrong with the alignment?

Thanks

Comment: what specifically are you having problems with? What should it be doing/not doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I will advice you strip your code of all inline styles, and the put every successive that should be on the same column in a div / section of class row. Bootstrap is based on the 12-grid system. That means once 12 columns are complete, the last element is dropped to a new line. Try these and see what will happen.